# Eclipse Code Assist with Composite Component and Custom Namespace fails

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, taglib, composite-component

I made a composite component and declared a custom namespace in my taglib like this:

```
[...]
<namespace>http://www.#####.info/components</namespace>
<composite-library-name>composites</composite-library-name>
[...]
```

Now when I use that namespace:

```
xmlns:wb="http://www.#####.info/components"
```

Everything 'works Runtime' but Eclipse wont show any Code assist like when I use the 'default' namespace:

```
xmlns:wbcomposites="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composites"
```

Is this a normal Eclipse behaviour or did I do something wrong ?

Edit:

For example when i write:

```
<wb:
```

And then press [STRG] + [SPACE] the code assist shows me that there are no components.
I think this behaviour would make the "user" think that he has done something wrong ...

I hope there is a way to fix this from my side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i mixed a normal component and a composite in the taglib:

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://abc/components</namespace>

    <composite-library-name>composites</composite-library-name>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>something</tag-name>
        <component>
[...]
```

Now i splitted them into to taglibs and two namespaces ...

This solved also bugs were the normal component was looked up as composite ...